Line numbers didn't show correctly using lineno package with 2 columns
I encountered an issue while submitting a manuscript to a journal under Elsevier. I used the lineno package to add line numbers to my document. When compiling locally using Overleaf, the line numbers are displayed correctly. However, after submitting the LaTeX source code to the journal's submission platform for online compilation, the line numbers became misaligned. Some line numbers that are supposed to appear on the left show up on the right, and vice versa. Additionally, line numbers that should appear on the next page show up on the current page.

one of the pictures with incorrect line numbers



what it supposed to be


After searching for potential solutions, I found some suggestions that point to floating objects like figures or tables as the cause. However, even after removing all figures, tables, and leaving just the text and references, the issue still persists on the last page.

after delete pictures and tables etc. the error still exists


I also consulted GPT, but it wasn't able to provide any useful modification suggestions.

the following is some of my letax code

\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{amsmath, bm}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}
\usepackage{lineno}

\begin{document}
\let\WriteBookmarks\relax
\def\floatpagepagefraction{1}
\def\textpagefraction{.001}
\let\printorcid\relax

\shorttitle{Sample Title}
\shortauthors{Author et al.}

\title [mode = title]{Minimal Working Example}  
\author[1]{Author Name}
\maketitle

\linenumbers
\pagewiselinenumbers
\switchlinenumbers

\section{Introduction}
This is Introduction. \citep{cityscapes}

\section{Figure Example}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Figure}
\end{figure}

bra bra bra

\section{xxx}
equation:

\begin{eqnarray}
    E = mc^2
\end{eqnarray}

algorithm:

\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption{Finding algorithmic}
    \label{alg:algorithmic}
    \begin{algorithmic}
        \STATE \RETURN L
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

table:

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \caption{table}
    \label{tab:table}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc} \toprule
            & \textbf{AP\(^{test}\)}& \textbf{AP}\\ \midrule
         xxx& 73.6& 99.7\\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\section{Conclusion}
conclusion

\nolinenumbers
\bibliographystyle{cas-model2-names}
\bibliography{ref}
\end{document}

Additionally, I would like to clarify that the Elsevier default template package includes several files: cas-dc-template.tex, cas-common.sty, and cas-sc.cls. The revised sample also requires a ref.bib file for references.
I suspect the problem is related to the two-column layout, as the misalignment seems to stem from line numbers that are supposed to appear in the other column or on the next page. I would sincerely appreciate any help or insights to resolve this issue. Thank you very much in advance for any potential solutions!

Are you sure that this is a minimal example?

Well, I have revised the original code. The current one includes an image, a formula, and a table.
